# Java simple for loop does not iterate

Tags: java, for-loop, loops

During execution the method is called and the integer `i` displays as `0` on screen. However, no output is forthcoming from inside the for loop, suggesting the for loop doesnt execute. I have also tested this with breakpoints, and have obtained the same results. Any help is appreciated.

```
private void decrypt_btnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    int ciphertext_length = Ciphertext().length();
    String decrypted_char = "";
    int i = 0;

    System.out.println("increment" + i);    

    try {
        for (i = 0; i == ciphertext_length; i++) {

            System.out.println("test" + i);

            String cipher_current_char = getLetterAtIndex(Ciphertext(), i);
            int pos_char_in_alphabet = getIndexAtLetter(Alphabet(), cipher_current_char);

            decrypted_char = decrypted_char +
                getLetterAtIndex(Alphabet(), pos_char_in_alphabet - 5);

            status_label.setText(100 / i + "%");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

    plain_ta.setText(decrypted_char);
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? You are just ignoring them in your catch block, so that would be hard to tell right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
  for (i = 0; i==ciphertext_length; i++){
```

should in all likelihood be

```
  for (i = 0; i<ciphertext_length; i++){
```

Comment: then you need to debug some more. What is the value of `ciphertext_length`?

Comment: String ciphertext="afRcXFBxXTRJ" : it can be any random string of base64 chars

Comment: ciphertext_length=ciphertext.length();

Comment: No, what is the actual value as shown in the debugger. I imagine Ciphertext() is not returning what you expect it to.